# Can a Deployment Subtopic contain deployment instructions for Administrators

Tags: java, deployment, websphere

I have following Questions related to WebSphere application server.

Does the Application assembly compile all the files related to application.

Does WAS create any EAR's

Can WAR modules be deployed independently deployed on WAS

Are there any restrictions on the naming of EAR or WAR to be deployed.

Can a Deployment Subtopic contain deployment instructions for Administrators

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere doesn't compile the code. It just deploys the EAR or WAR.

I believe   modules cant be deployed independently